# A constant function

Tags: functions

$f:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded above and satisfies 
$$f(n)\le \frac{f(n+1)+f(n-1)}{2}$$
Does it follow $f$ is constant ?
There was a dreadful typo in the [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835712/a-proof-of-constancy) question (in the previous question, the domain of $f$ was $\mathbb N$, here, it is $\mathbb Z$), I am posting a new one. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Look at $g(n)=f(n)-f(n-1)$ - what can you say about $g$?

Comment: @5xum Someone edited the previous question to be identical to this one.

Comment: @StevenTaschuk I retracted my vote. I will also edit this question so no-one will make the same mistake as me.

Comment: To all of you sirs, I am terribly sorry I made a mistake in writing down the problem and sorry you all had to go through that trouble. Thanks a lot for all helpful comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an extended hint

Let $g(n)=f(n)-f(n-1)$, or $f(n)=f(n-1)+g(n)$ so the condition becomes $$g(n+1)\ge g(n)$$

Suppose $g(N)=a\gt 0$, can you say anything about $f(N+r)$?

Suppose $g(N)=b\lt 0$, what can you say about $f(N-r)$?